# How do I change the 'YYMMDD' - > 'YYYY-MM-DD' in dayjs?

Tags: typescript, dayjs

How to change YYMMDD -> YYYY-MM-DD in dayjs

`const startDateString = dayjs(createdAtStart).startOf('day').format()`
`const endDateString = dayjs(createdAtEnd).endOf('day').format()`

Comment: Have you looked at [custom-parse-format](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/custom-parse-format)? So loading the plugin and then `dayjs(createdAtStart, 'YYMMDD', true).format('YYYY-MM-DD')` I believe ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for (if dayJS doesn't parse YYMMDD out of the box) is the following plugin: [custom_parse_format](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/custom-parse-format).

First you add the plugin (see docs under "Plugins" how to load plugin for NodeJS or browser):

```
var customParseFormat = require('dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat')
dayjs.extend(customParseFormat)
```

Then you can parse a custom date format like YYMMDD:

```
dayjs(createdAtStart, 'YYMMDD').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Of course, you can replace `format` with any other method or chain of methods.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/format) use `.format('YYYY-MM-DD')`.

```js
const formated = dayjs('1. 1. 2023').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
console.log(formated);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.7/dayjs.min.js" integrity="sha512-hcV6DX35BKgiTiWYrJgPbu3FxS6CsCjKgmrsPRpUPkXWbvPiKxvSVSdhWX0yXcPctOI2FJ4WP6N1zH+17B/sAA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: nono i want like this ex) 230101 -> 20230101

Answer (score 0):

```
const dateString1 = "20230209150300";
const pattern1 = /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/;
const formatedDate1 = dateString1.replace(pattern1, '$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6');
```